# How can i show a question to user in Laravel that isn't viewed previously?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables `users` and `questions`
`questions` table has over 5000 questions that can be viewed by users.
I want one user to view one random question at a time and once only,
Once the question is viewed by a user it should not be viewed again by that particular user.

Example of `users` table:

```
id | name        | email
-------------------------
 1 | John Doe    | abc@example.com
 2 | Mary        | def@example.com
```

Example of `questions` table:

```
id | title       | description
-------------------------
 1 | ABC         | Some dsc
 2 | DEF         | Some dsc
```

So i created another table named `skips` that stores viewed `question_id` and `user_id`
table has `user_id` and `question_id` column
Example of `skips` table:

```
id | user_id     | question_id
-------------------------
 1 | 1           | 1
 2 | 1           | 2
```

For example: `user_id` of number `1` has already viewed both questions with id 1 and 2

Now here's my question
**How can i show a question to user in Laravel that isn't viewed previously using eloquent relationships?**

Comment: Hint: you can use `not in`

Comment: @catcon something like this: `Question::all()->whereNotIn('skips', ...)->ramdom();`?
What should i pass to skips?

Comment: I don't know about the eloquent, but this query maybe work `SELECT * FROM question WHERE question_id not in (select question_id from skips where user_id = 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have acheived this by:

```
Question::whereNotIn('id', Skip::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
          ->get('question_id'))
          ->get()
          ->random();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereNotIn()` and supply a subquery where you select all the questions that a user has answered.

```
Questions::whereNotIn('id', \DB::table("skips")
                               ->select("question_id")
                               ->where("user_id", \Auth::id()))
                               ->toArray()
         ->random();
```

If you have a relation called "skips" properly defined (which *gets* the answered questions), you can use `doesntHave()`,

```
Questions::doesntHave('skips')->random();
```

- [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

Answer (score 0):

In laravel, Many ways to achieve your desired result. relationship is the best solution.

```
$skip = Skips::where('user_id', $user_id)->select('question_id')->toArray();
$questions = Questions::select(*)->whereNotIn('question_id', $skip)->toArray();
```

Comment: You usually don't define a model of a pivot table. That's what relations are for.